# I am unable to web-scrape a URL from a hyperlink in this website. | Web-scrape, Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am unable to get the links from this website called: https://riwayat-file-vaksinasi-dki-jakarta-jakartagis.hub.arcgis.com/

I use the following code:

```
import requests
import bs4

req = requests.get('https://riwayat-file-vaksinasi-dki-jakarta-jakartagis.hub.arcgis.com/')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
```

When I use this code, I am unable to find the source for the links that I want.

```
soup.body
```

The code above returns the following output:

```
<body class="calcite">
<div aria-label="loading" id="base-loader">
<svg class="loader-square loader-square-1" viewbox="0 0 56 56" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect height="56" width="56"></rect>
</svg>
<svg class="loader-square loader-square-2" viewbox="0 0 56 56" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect height="56" width="56"></rect>
</svg>
<svg class="loader-square loader-square-3" viewbox="0 0 56 56" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect height="56" width="56"></rect>
</svg>
<div class="loader-bars"></div>
</div>
<script>
      if (typeof customElements !== 'undefined') {
        customElements.efineday = customElements.define;
      }
    </script>
<!-- crossorigin options added because otherwise we cannot see error messages from unhandled errors and rejections -->
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://hubcdn.arcgis.com/opendata-ui/assets/assets/vendor-c4dd10aa0ad3c0cd3c74b496637f5da5.js"></script>
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://hubcdn.arcgis.com/opendata-ui/assets/assets/opendata-ui-01a5d313fd3d0fe1fa17d9270ab5c456.js"></script>
<div id="ember-basic-dropdown-wormhole"></div>
<!-- opendata-ui version: 5.171.0+6ac420726b - Tue, 05 Oct 2021 18:03:32 GMT -->
</body>
```

I cant seem to find any drive links on the HTML body text above.

[image: I want to get the drive links from each hyperlink]

I want to get all of the google drive links from that hyperlinks on the **left column**

Comment: page is dynamically rendered. You need to use someting like Selenium that allows the page to render first, and then can use beautifulsoup, or find the api (if there is one) to fetch it directly

Comment: If for whatever reason the approach proposed by @chitown88 could not be implemented, you can still get to the google drive links by analyzing the **head** instead of the **body**. The links are in the URL-encoded blob inside the `<script id="site-injection">` tag

Comment: @tromgy, good catch. I didn't see that there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Selenium` solution:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
driver.get("https://riwayat-file-vaksinasi-dki-jakarta-jakartagis.hub.arcgis.com/")
time.sleep(3)  # wait for page to download
links = [i.get_attribute('href') for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td p a")]
print(links)
driver.quit()
```

If you didn't use `Selenium` before, do not forget to install [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

2. `requests` + `urllib.parse` solution (inspired by the comment of @tromgy)

```py
import requests
import bs4
from urllib.parse import unquote

req = requests.get('https://riwayat-file-vaksinasi-dki-jakarta-jakartagis.hub.arcgis.com/')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
url = unquote(soup.select_one("script#site-injection").string[23:].strip())

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url,"lxml")
links = [i['href'][2:-2] for i in soup.select("td p a")]
links
```

If you want to get only the **left column** of the table, then use `td:first-of-type p a` as css selector. It simply inspects the first `td` element and ignore the second (right) one.